# "Elbow push" English analogy

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm trying to figure out an English expression for something that we have in my native language and I can't seem to find one.

When someone's speaking publicly, and says something wrong or something they're not supposed to, another person standing next to the speaker might give them a comical "elbow push", to signal (to both the person and the audience) that's one should correct themselves.

That's what we call it - "elbow push" - from where I'm from.

Here's a animated gif to illustrate the situation.

https://media.giphy.com/media/3oFzm6N9pmmtM7bq9i/giphy.gif

Is there an idiom for that?

UPDATE: edited the picture to avoid confusion

Comment: To be clear, are you talking about using your elbow to touch their body, or using your finger to touch their shoulder?

Comment: The thing illustrated in the image is a "shoulder tap".  An "elbow bump" these days is where two people bump elbows instead of shaking hands, and an "elbow punch" is where someone shoves their elbow into the side of the person beside them.

Comment: (Look up the difference between "elbow" and "shoulder".)

Comment: @HotLicks The picture illutrated the situation (someone wants to correct other person publicly). It can be a shoulder tap, a loud "cough-cough" etc.

Comment: I would simply call it a _nudge_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the GIF, Joey is *poking* Chandler.

But you can poke someone for a variety of reasons. I think the word that you're looking for is *nudge*. From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nudge):

> 1: to touch or push gently
> ...
> especially : to seek the attention of by a push of the elbow
> *nudged Ron in the ribs and pointed at Malfoy*
> — J. K. Rowling

I don't think there's an English idiom that's as specific as in your native language. As in the example above, the reason for the nudge will usually be clarified.

Comment: Yes, `poking` and `nudge` seem good, I guess that's what I was looking for

Comment: @jsw29 I don't think there's a word that's that specific. Notice that in the example from Harry Potter, the reason for the nudge was made clear. I think that will practically always be the case.

Comment: I'd say I *kicked him under the table* to mean I gave him a private signal to say *wake up*.

Comment: I would definitely call what is happening in the gif a _nudge_.